# new Thread, application still running after Stage-close

Tags: multithreading, javafx-8

So I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyyj57O0FVI

and I made exactly the same code in javafx8.

```
public class CountdownController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Label labTime;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                String time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

                labTime.setText(time);
            }

        }
    }.start();
}
```

After I close the Window, application/thread is still running in the system. My guess its because the infinite loop, but shouldnt the thread be terminated with application closing?

Second thing is that when I try to set the text for Label I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:364)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:364)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$60(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$$Lambda$144/1099655841.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:143)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:146)
    at application.CountdownController$1.run(CountdownController.java:29)
```

...yes, I am going to read more about threads, but I would like to know the answer to these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Part I**

A thread, when created, runs independent of other threads. You have a new thread which has an infinite loop, which implies, it will keep running forever, even after the stage has been closed.

Normally, using a infinite loop is not advised, because breaking out of it is very difficult.

You are advised to use :

- [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)
- [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

You can then call either one of them (based on whatever you are using)

- [TimerTask.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29)
- [ScheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

when your stage is closed. You can use something like :

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(closeEvent -> {
       timertask.cancel();  
});
```

**JavaFX API's** *(thanks to James_D comment's)*

These do not need to be explicitly canceled as `ScheduledService` uses daemon threads and `AnimationTimer` runs on the JavaFX thread.

- [ScheduledService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html)
- [AnimationTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html)

### **Part II**

Your second part of the question has been answered time and again in the forum.

> You need to be on the JavaFX Application thread to use scene graph elements.

Since you have created a new thread and trying to update `label`, which is a JavaFX node, it throws the exception. For more information, please visit:

[JavaFX error when trying to remove shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243551/javafx-error-when-trying-to-remove-shape)

[Why am I getting java.lang.IllegalStateException "Not on FX application thread" on JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850191/why-am-i-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-on-javafx)

[Javafx Not on fx application thread when using timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916640/javafx-not-on-fx-application-thread-when-using-timer)

Comment: You can still use the long-running thread if you prefer; just call `setDaemon(true);`  on it before starting it; then it will not prevent application closure. I would recommend using some kind of high-level scheduling API though; also see [`ScheduledService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) and [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html). I would at least recommend your thread sleep for some time on each iteration, so it doesn't consume as much CPU as it can grab.

Comment: @James_D It just slipped off my mind that there are JavaFX API's as well. Thanks, I will add them to the answer. Though, `setDaemon(true)` is a solution, I wouldn't suggest user to use it without understanding what it does.

Comment: so I can also declare `boolean close=false;` and `while(true && (close =! false){...` and `stage.setOnCloseRequest(closeEvent -> {
       close = true;  
});  `   Im gonna check the links tho.

Comment: No you can't as variables used inside lambdas must be `final` or `effectively final`. Though you may use AtomicBoolean for your use case, and you won't need `true` inside while. Just make sure you make the thread sleep for sometime to avoid unnecessary CPU usage as suggested by @James_D. Again, using a high level API, as suggested in the solution, is highly recommended.

Comment: You *should* use `AtomicBoolean` in the above use case, to ensure liveness of the variable `close`, which is being accessed from multiple threads. But I really would not advise doing things this way.

Comment: If you use either `ScheduledService` or `AnimationTimer` there is no need to explicitly stop them. `ScheduledService` uses daemon threads by default, so they will not prevent application shutdown. `AnimationTimer` just executes on the FX Application Thread. I think for displaying a clock, I would use an `AnimationTimer`.

Comment: Ohh.. ScheduledService generates daemon thread, my bad. Got so much to learn!! Thanks @James_D

Comment: @ItachiUchiha should I use `Platform.runLater(() -> ` to acces Label, or do You know better, maybe more proper solution?

Comment: @Tomek I would suggest to use a `ScheduledService` pass a Task to it, update the Task's message using [`updateMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-) and bind the Task's [`messageProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#messageProperty--) to the Label's [`textProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textProperty--).

Answer (score 2):

With `ScheduledExecutorService` as far as I am concerned You cant easly set it as deamon and I don't want to play with `stage.setOnCloseRequest(closeEvent -> {});`

With AnimationTimer I cant do something like `Thread.sleep(100)` beetween iteration like you suggested because *"AnimationTimer runs on the JavaFX thread."*

`ScheduledService` is just quite difficult for me to understand right now...

so, as I was reading and reading about it I came to conclusion that maybe this simple option will be the best:

```
public class CountdownController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Label labTime;
@FXML
private Button buttSTOP;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     Timer timer = new Timer(true); //set it as a deamon
     timer.schedule(new MyTimer(), 0, 1000);
}


public class MyTimer extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        String time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            labTime.setText(time);
        });

    }
}
```

Thanks **James_D** and **ItachiUchiha**. It works, let me know if I'am something missing!

EDIT: 
I also include code for Counting down the time, as it was my initial aim, maybe someone will find it usefull as well:

```
public class CountdownController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Label labTime;
@FXML
private Button buttSTOP;

private Timer timer = new Timer(true); //set it as a deamon
private int iHours = 0,
            iMinutes = 1,
            iSeconds = 10;  


public void initCountdownController(int iHours, int iMinutes, int iSeconds){
    this.iHours = iHours;
    this.iMinutes = iMinutes;
    this.iSeconds = iSeconds;
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    buttSTOP.setOnAction(e -> {
        buttSTOPAction(e);
    });
    timer.schedule(new MyTimer(), 0, 1000);
}
private void buttSTOPAction(ActionEvent e) {
    timer.cancel();
}
public class MyTimer extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String time = iHours + ":" + iMinutes + ":" + iSeconds;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            labTime.setText(time);
        });

        if(iSeconds < 1)
            if(iMinutes < 1)
                if(iHours < 1)
                    this.cancel();
                else{
                    iHours--;
                    iMinutes = 59;
                    iSeconds = 59;
                }
            else{
                iMinutes--;
                iSeconds = 59;
            }
        else
            iSeconds--;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really great to see somebody evaluate options, learn from them and come up with their own useful independent answer.