# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Not on FX application when using quartz

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to use a javafx alert in a task schedule in quartz:

```
public class ChecarJob implements Job{
    private Connection con;
    public ChecarJob() {
        this.con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Executou!");
                try {
                    String verStatus = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM equipamento_requisicao";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(verStatus);
                        ResultSet rsStatus = stmt.executeQuery();
                        if(rsStatus.next()){
                        Alerts a = new Alerts();
                        int Resultado = rsStatus.getInt(1);
                        if(Resultado>Sessao.getInstancia().getQtdRegistroBD()){
                        Sessao.getInstancia().setQtdRegistroBD(Resultado);
                                                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("SUCESS");
                        alert.setHeaderText("SUCESS");
                        alert.setContentText("SUCESS");
                        alert.showAndWait();
                        }
                        else if(Resultado<Sessao.getInstancia().getQtdRegistroBD()){
                        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("FAIL");
                        alert.setHeaderText("FAIL");
                        alert.setContentText("FAIL");
                        alert.showAndWait();
                        Sessao.getInstancia().setQtdRegistroBD(Resultado);
                        } 
                        else{
                        //aq não irei fazer nada.
                        }
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }   

}
```

calling in my main class:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    JobDetail j = JobBuilder.newJob(ChecarJob.class).build();
    Trigger t = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("CroneTrigger")
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(60).repeatForever()).build();
    Scheduler s = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    s.start();
    s.scheduleJob(j,t);
```

msg do error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2Executou!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting java.lang.IllegalStateException "Not on FX application thread" on JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850191/why-am-i-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-on-fx-application-thread)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449297/java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-on-fx-application-thread-currentthread-t

Comment: i try but not sucess :( maybe with timertask not problem .

Comment: Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        new Thread() {
        JobDetail j = JobBuilder.newJob(ChecarJob.class).build();
        Trigger t = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("CroneTrigger")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(60).repeatForever()).build();
        Scheduler s = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        s.start();
        s.scheduleJob(j,t);
        }.start();
        });

Comment: can help mee pls?

Comment: Inside the job you need to execute the code that modifies the UI on the _JavaFX Application Thread_, and only the code that modifies the UI.

Comment: u can help me with reply? i vote + please . 
I am new to java and do not understand much about threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX, like most UI toolkits, is single-threaded and not thread-safe. Once a scene graph is being displayed in a window, it must only be interacted with on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. And some objects must be *instantiated* on the FX thread. To do otherwise can lead to errors, as you've encountered, or just full on *undefined behavior*. If you're on a background thread and you need to schedule an action with the FX thread, you can use [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) (link is to the Javadoc).

Your code is not a minimal and complete example, so I can't be sure of what everything does. In general, however, I would start by moving all the code relating to `Alert` instances into a `runLater` call.

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Executou!");
    try {
        String verStatus = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM equipamento_requisicao";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(verStatus);
        ResultSet rsStatus = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rsStatus.next()) {
            Alerts a = new Alerts(); // what does this do?
            int Resultado = rsStatus.getInt(1);
            if (Resultado > Sessao.getInstancia().getQtdRegistroBD()) {
                Sessao.getInstancia().setQtdRegistroBD(Resultado); // unknown side-effects
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("SUCESS");
                    alert.setHeaderText("SUCESS");
                    alert.setContentText("SUCESS");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                });
            } else if (Resultado < Sessao.getInstancia().getQtdRegistroBD()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("FAIL");
                    alert.setHeaderText("FAIL");
                    alert.setContentText("FAIL");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                });
                Sessao.getInstancia().setQtdRegistroBD(Resultado); // unknown side-effects
            } else {
                //aq não irei fazer nada.
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- The above uses [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).
- *Don't forget to close resources (e.g. `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet`) when done with them. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).*
- The calls to `runLater` do *not* wait for the `Runnable` to return.
- The "unknown side-effects" comments are there because I have no idea if those method invocations modify the UI. I've left them out of the `runLater` call on the assumption that they don't.
- I couldn't find where `Alerts a = new Alerts()` is actually used.
- The name `Resultado` does not follow standard Java naming conventions for local variables.
- Notice that properly indenting your code makes it much easier to read and follow what is happening.

---

> I am new to java and do not understand much about threads

Not having at least a basic understanding of concurrency in Java will hinder your efforts to create all but the most trivial of GUI applications. I highly recommend you study this topic before moving forward. As a *start*, read these:

- [Lesson: Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Also, a good book on the topic is *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz et al.

Comment: thanks  
I had forgotten to close stament and prepared
These alerts I will use in case I have a new record added in the database so I do a routine every 10 minutes

Comment: and i found this for fix shutdown:                                   stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            try {
                s.shutdown();
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

Comment: I could not think very well how to overwrite the stop could you help me?